# ASP.Net Core 3.1 scaffolded Identity pages not all used (ie. Login page OK, Register page NOK)...why?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, scaffold

I just scaffolded successfully the Identity pages with the `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity` tool and added some custom code on Startup to populate some Roles.

Then I wanted to update the `/Areas/Identity/Pages/Register.cshtml.cs` file with some code to add custom Role to the newly created user...BUT the breakpoints in this page aren't reached.

- when I modify the HTML of Login.cshtml , it's OK, I see the changes and breakpoints in the .cs file are reached
- when I try to do the same thing in Register.cshtml, nothing is taken into account, custom HTML is not updated and breakpoints are never reached

Maybe I miss something in the Startup conf ?

---

**EDIT**

If I rename *Register.cshtml/.cs* to *Register2*, I can reach the TWO pages under the routes */Identity/Account/Register* and */Identity/Account/Register2*.

BUT when targeting `Register2`, the breakpoints are reached and HTML is up to date...

Maybe there is a hidden link with `IdentityHostingStartup` ?

---

Here it is :

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
                {
                    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                })
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


            services.AddAuthentication();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }

    }
```

Thanks a lot buddies ^^

Comment: How did you modify your Register.cshtml and Register.cshtml.cs?

Comment: I just changed the HTML to see how I could edit it..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo that how to add a role to the newly created User:

For your Startup.cs,no need to DI UserManager and RoleManager:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {           
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();           
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

For Register.cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bool x = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
            if (!x)
            {
                // first we create Admin role   
                var role = new IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "Admin";
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

            var data = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {                   
                   //...                                    
            }

        }
        return Page();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but it was not the problem I encountered. I did succeed in populating Roles and Users,etc..

My problem is that when I customize the HTML of Login page, I see the results, but when I customize the Register page, no change is visible, it seems the Identity framework chooses what to serve °-° 
Sometimes it serves the scaffolding pages, sometimes it seems to serve some DLL-hidden pages...

Just wanted to know why

Comment: So how did you change your Register.cshtml?I suggest that you could provide some code then we could help you.

Comment: Hi Rena, I only changed some HTML tags in the Register.cshtml page, just in order to see if I could customize the render. I didn't changed the code-behind.
Anyway, I think I'll re-create all the Identity pages by myself for 2 reasons : 
- having my own route/structure
- coding some additional rules for the registering and managing parts

Comment: If you just change the html in Register.cshtml.It could render well.How did you modify?

Comment: I know this problem is a few months old now. However, I had a similar problem in VS for Mac where I was pulling my hair out. The only way I have been able to resolve it was by removing the Register.cshtml file from visual studio then adding it back in as an existing file and rebuilding at which point my changes were visible otherwise it seems to use the one from the Razor Class Library DLL.

Comment: This happened for me for another page in the Identity and removing it and add it again to the project solved the issue.